How to use short path in include?
I use the following project structure, the problem is long import paths.
./deps/lib/base.jl
./experiments/play.jl

The problem is long relative dependency paths in ./experiments/play.jl, that also breaks when you refactor the code.
include("../deps/lib/base.jl")
println("hello")

Is there a way to make it shorter? Like:

Add deps/lib to JULIA_LOAD_PATH and use as include("base.jl").
Or define the lib alias and use as include("lib/base.jl")
Or use absolute path include("/deps/lib/base.jl") (not good, but still better than relative)

P.S. I really would like to avoid using module, packages etc. and keep the code as simple as possible, just a set of files, like python or ruby.
